# Java: In command line, Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I tried to run `DependencyParserDemo.java` in Stanford NLP parser.

I use Win7, jdk-10.0.1.

In command line:

```
Javac -cp stanford-parser.jar DependencyParserDemo.java
```

Works fine, `DependencyParserDemo.class` generated.

But when I run:

```
Java -cp stanford-parser.jar DependencyParserDemo
```

It shows:

```
Error: Could not find or load mian class DependencyParserDemo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DependencyParserDemo
```

Maybe the classpath setting is wrong?

Comment: is ``DependencyParserDemo`` declared in any package?

Comment: Nope, not in any package

Comment: use `java -cp .;stanford-parser.jar DependencyParserDemo` . You need to include the current working directory in the classpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need the location of the new class in  your classpath.

```
Java -cp stanford-parser.jar;. DependencyParserDemo
```

Comment: Now it gives me: Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tragger model(probably missing model file)

Comment: Now your code starts.  And it has a bug.  Time to start understanding what you did.